# What is the `@Name@` in command line?

Tags: bash, tsung

I'm looking for Tsung source code. There is a line like following in file [tsung.sh.in](https://github.com/processone/tsung/blob/master/tsung.sh.in):

`ERL_OPTS=" $ERL_DIST_PORTS -smp auto +P $MAX_PROCESS +A 16 +K true @ERL_OPTS@ "`

What does the `@ERL_OPTS@` mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be something that gets substituted by autoconf during the build process.

Generally, a `.in` file gets preprocessed by some build script. Autoconf uses `@IDENTIFIER@` to indicate the place where the actual value has to be put in. The preprocessed version loses the `.in` extension, thus generating `tsung.sh` in this particular case.